# how to find source code of particular Inkscape functions

Tags: function, open-source, inkscape

I want to have a look at the sourcecode for Inkscape's Path->Outset and ->Inset functions. How do I go about finding it in the source code? I'm looking at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/trunk/files
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most straightforward is to just download the source code and use your favorite search utility to search all files for the name of the function in the file contents. Some of the matches will be function calls and not definitions, but you'll sift through those quickly enough.

If you do this alot though, consider loading it as a project into an IDE like visual studio. Then you can just right click any function name in any file and the context menu will offer you options like "goto definition", which will open the correct file and navigate you to the correct line.